# How to fix exception "class MyClass was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it"

Tags: ios, objective-c

I get this exception "class MyClass was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it", I want to know how can I fix it?

I think it is caused by the following code.
      __block MyClass *aClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];

```
  [aClass addObserver:observer
         forKeyPath:@"aKey"
         options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
         context:context];
```

My question is I don't see where in the does the dealloc and what should I do to unregister before MyClass get dealloc?

Thank you.

Comment: What is `proxy` and `observer` ? And where did you declared the `aClass` ?

Comment: I usually work with `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` and `- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated` methods in order to add and remove observers. Edit: I suppose you're in the presentation context and you're working with view controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the docs for the method `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:`? The answer is right there, under the "Discussion" section. The important part:

> ...An object that calls this method must also call either the
>   removeObserver:forKeyPath: or removeObserver:forKeyPath:context:
>   method when participating in KVO.

So if the code you posted is in your init method, you need to add a call to `removeObserver:forKeyPath:` or `removeObserver:forKeyPath:context:` in your dealloc method.

Comment: The method you mentioned is applicable when A adds observer for B in it's init and A removes it in it's dealloc. What happens if B is deallocated before A ?, will it cause any issues ?

Comment: That's fine. And object that has been deallocated can't very well send KVO change notices about changes to properties that no longer exist.